# Based on the eigen structure, What applications of discrete sine/cosine transformations can be found?

Tags: image-processing, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, image-compression

I am a PH.D in mathematics. I am interested in finding some applications of discrete Sine/Cosine transformations (**DTTs**) that are based on the eigenvectors.

I have found some results concerning computing the eigenvectors of **DTTs**. Indeed they suggest some ways to find them approximately (See for examples [Tseng](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/992133) and [Pei](http://ntur.lib.ntu.edu.tw/bitstream/246246/142470/1/60.pdf)).

> Q. Suppose that we have determined a basis of eigen-vectors for some type of discrete Sine/Cosine transformations. Based on  having this  knowledge in this particular  issue, what applications  will be leaded to find?

Comment: The first link you included talks about a watermarking scheme. That’s where you embed a mark into an image in a way that is not noticeable, is hard to remove without destroying the image, and can be used to prove the image’s origin.

Answer (score 0):

Discrete Cosine transform (2D-DCT) is used in image compression. I've used DCT (1D DCT), for audio compression . Transmitting/storing the first few DCT transform values, is sufficient to recover the entire file/signal , which is nothing but compression

Comment: Thanks, Could you please give some more details concerning the role of the eigenvectors?